# How to create Table Layout for Cafe/Restaurant in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I want to create a table layout for Cafe/Restaurant and have interaction such positioning and get (x,y)-coordinate-like position.

Any widget suggestion to achieve this case?

**Expected Table Layout**

[image: Expected Table Layout]

Comment: Hi, have you figured out a solution for this?